# How can i set meta tag for every social share in angular 5?

Tags: angular, facebook, typescript, angular5

I am working on a project that has social share functionality. Currently I can share links in Facebook, twitter, gmail. I want to share its og:image and description for every post i share socially.
Please suggest, how can this can be achieved.

So when i share it should something like this.
[image]

Comment: You mean sharing a photo as status on Facebook/Twitter by a request sent by your application?

Comment: No, i just want to share its link. But when i send that link to someone in messenger or skype Others should be able to see the image and captions as meta tags. Do you need a screenshot for reference ? @JacopoSciampi

Comment: Oh, ok. Now I've understand. Can you add the reference to the API you are using? I mean, I know it's the standard facebook API, in this case, but can you add the link you are following?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{SERVER_URL}}/user/post-view/{{shareLinkPost.id}}  -- For facebook  @JacopoSciampi